# I need to stop an import.io crawler and extract the data it has pulled thus far. How do I do it without losing the data?

Tags: web-crawler, import.io

I am using import.io's batch query feature to crawl 25K URLs. It started out fast but started to slow down tremendously at around 10K. It has been more than 6 hours now and it is at 19K. I unfortunately don't have time to wait until it is done so I need to make do with whatever data it has gathered thus far.

However, I don't see a stop button or anything and I am afraid of losing the data if I mess around with it too much.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! How are we supposed to know, if we do not even know how the crawler works? We haven't seen any code, nor how you use it.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I am actually using their extractor. Hopefully this picture helps. Sorry for the trouble :/ http://screencast.com/t/PghYH5n47

Comment: @cfi forgot to tag you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extractor software speeds up and slows down according to how fast the website is serving the pages and a bunch of other factors, to make sure the stand the best chance of getting all the data; we do it this way as we think data quality and coverage are paramount, so getting a quick, but low quality, dataset is not something we believe in. After all you've probably heard of 'rubbish in rubbish out' before :)

In the future, you can contact the development/support team at http://support.import.io/ for help with data extraction.

Good luck